# How to create an expression call with function createdatetime?

Tags: c#, parameters, expression

I am trying to create an expression call with a six parameter function `CreateDateTime`, in the expression I am a beginner, anybody help? thks.

Here is the result what I want to get

```
m => m.OpenDate >= EntityFunctions.CreateDateTime(2012, 12, 22, 0, 0, 0)
```

and when I try to write this but an exception always arises.

```
Expression.Call(typeof(EntityFunctions), "CreateDateTime",
      new Type[]
          {
            typeof(int?), typeof(int?), typeof(int?), 
            typeof(int?), typeof(int?), typeof(double?)
          }, 
      new Expression[]
          {
            Expression.Constant(2012),
            Expression.Constant(12),
            Expression.Constant(22),
            Expression.Constant(0),
            Expression.Constant(0),
            Expression.Constant(0.0)
          }
     );
```

Comment: What exception. Compile time or runtime.

Comment: **What does the error say?**

Comment: the error is can't not find the CreateDateTime Function match what the parameter supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here can solv it

```
Expression.Call(typeof(EntityFunctions), "CreateDateTime",
  new Type[]
      {
        typeof(int?), typeof(int?), typeof(int?), 
        typeof(int?), typeof(int?), typeof(double?)
      }, 
  new Expression[]
      {
        Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(2012),typeof(int?)),
        Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(12),typeof(int?)),
        Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(22),typeof(int?)),
        Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(0),typeof(int?)),
        Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(0),typeof(int?)),
        Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(0.0),typeof(double?)),
      }
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime` class already has a constructor which takes these parameters to create a `DateTime` object.

Comment: Bu EF's query translator doesnt' recognize it.

Comment: I want to use it in the Linq to Entity. and use to compare with the Datetime value, i test that code can work, other will raise exception:Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported